# Integrate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{1+x^{12}}$using partial fractions

Tags: calculus, integration

How do I integrate the improper integral  $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{1+x^{12}}$$ using partial fraction decomposition?

I am restricted to use only the principles taught in Calculus 2, which entails partial fraction decomposition. I have tried factoring the denominator but was quickly stumped at the complicated roots. I am unsure of how to proceed. I even thought of looking at it as a series but I don't think I can do that.

Thank you very much for your help. I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: This doesn't have any roots over $\Bbb R$ so a partial fraction decomposition is going to be pretty challenging. Wolfram Alpha gives the solution in terms of a product of gamma functions as well.

Comment: Using half-angle identities one can compute the complex roots $e^{ik\pi/12} = \cos(k\pi/12) + i\sin(k\pi/12)$ to get the roots over $\Bbb C$, then combine the conjugate terms to get the factorization of the denominator over $\Bbb R$.  This is ugly and I don't see any nicer way off the top of my head.

Comment: Parentheses, please.  What you wrote is the integral of $1+x^{12}$, but I am sure you meant $1/(1+x^{12})$  If you know where the roots of $-1$ are, you can group them in conjugate pairs to get a factorization of $1+x^{12}$ into real quadratics

Comment: [the factorization](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x%5E2%2Bsqrt%282%29x%2B1%29%28x%5E2-sqrt%282%29x%2B1%29%28x%5E2%2B%28sqrt%283%29-1%29%2Fsqrt%282%29*x%2B1%29%28x%5E2-%28sqrt%283%29-1%29%2Fsqrt%282%29*x%2B1%29%28x%5E2%2B%28sqrt%283%29%2B1%29%2Fsqrt%282%29*x%2B1%29%28x%5E2-%28sqrt%283%29%2B1%29%2Fsqrt%282%29*x%2B1%29) is $(x^2\pm\sqrt{2}x+1)(x^2\pm\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{\sqrt{2}}x+1)(x^2\pm\frac{\sqrt{3}+1}{\sqrt{2}}x+1)$ ($\pm$ are for short, every parenthesis counts 2 times, for $+$ and for $-$) @Sam

Comment: Someone edit this question

Comment: Residues using a pie slice :)

Answer (score 11):

Apply the partial fractions

$$ \frac{6}{1+x^{12}}
=\frac2{x^4+1}-\frac{\sqrt3x^2-2}{x^4-\sqrt3x^2+1} 
 + \frac{\sqrt3x^2+2}{x^4+\sqrt3x^2+1} $$

to integrate

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{1+x^{12}}
=\frac23 J(0) +\frac{2+\sqrt3}3 J(\sqrt3)+ \frac{2-\sqrt3}3 J(-\sqrt3)$$

where

\begin{align}
J(a) &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x^4+ax^2+1}
=\frac\pi{\sqrt{2+a}}\\
\end{align}

Evaluate $J(a)$ with $a=0, \pm \sqrt3$ to obtain

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{1+x^{12}} = \frac{(\sqrt3+1)\pi}{3\sqrt2}$$

Comment: I am getting $\frac{1}{6} (\pi cosec \left(\frac{\pi}{12}\right))$

Comment: @Ercanayan which is equal to $\frac{\sqrt3+1}{3\sqrt2}\pi$

Comment: your answer doesnt involve $\pi$

Comment: @Ercanayan it’s overlooked; will fix.

Comment: I'm a little confused: why is there no $6$s in the denominator in the RHS of the line just after "to integrate"? And why can you ignore $x^2$ in the numerator? Thanks.

Comment: @BenjaminWang - These particular partial fractions happen to exclude the 6s in the denominator. Also note that $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x^4+ax^2+1}
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x^2\ dx}{x^4+ax^2+1}
$$

Answer (score 6):

To help you get started:
$u^4 + 1 =
u^4 + 2u^2 + 1 - 2u^2 $. 
Then write as a difference of squares and factor.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$\frac{1}{x^{12}+1}=\sum_{k=0}^{5}\left(\frac{A_k}{x-x_k}+\frac{\bar A_k}{x-\bar x_k}\right)$
where $x_k=\exp\left(\frac{(2k+1)\pi i}{12}\right)$ gives
$A_k=-\frac{x_k}{12}$ and hence that
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x^{12}+1}=\left(\sum_{k=0}^{5}\frac16\sin\left(\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{12}\right)\right)\pi$$